# Ubuntu 16.04 Failed to created shared shared memory file: Permission denied?

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, ubiquity

While installing ubuntu 16.04

I am getting:

```
Failed to create sharedmemoryfile /WK2SharedMemory.34567654: Permission denied
```

from the ubuntu installer at the stage of restoring previously installed packages.

Comment: The installer...I'm not in the terminal and can't see what command is doing that. Where is the installer log file?

Comment: Managed to sort this with selecting use 3rd party non-free stuff and I said Install alongside other OSes.

Comment: I have that too, when choosing to reinstall Ubuntu, so install alongside doesn't work for me

Comment: How dis you resolve this issue? I am having this too 

Comment: @richmondwang You can upvote the question then. Just redo with allowing 3rd party...

Comment: I just ran into this issue with 16.04.1, it happes when you reinstall without formatting the partition, where the Ubiquity Installer tries to restore the previously installed packages, during that stage Webkit seems to act up (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134892). I switched to a terminal and killed the Webkit process that consumed 100% CPU, the installation now continues with a lot of messages from the packages it tries to reinstall some of them look like permission errors, I'm not sure if these are sort of intended. I did almost the same on an external cloned drive b4  w/o issues

Answer (score 4):

As I wrote before in a comment: this happens when you reinstall without formatting the root partition (or partitions where the packages are stored e.g. /usr if you do such a thing). Ubiquity Installer tries to restore the previously installed packages and during that stage Webkit seems to act up. If you open a terminal and run `top` you will find a `WebKitWebProcess` consuming 100% CPU, kill it with `killall WebKitWebProcess` and the installation will continue. You may not be able to spawn a terminal when it already happened, instead switch to a virtual terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> login as user `ubuntu` with an empty password and kill the process there, be patient, it might take some time to perform this, then switch back to the GUI <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and wait for the installation to continue and complete.

I filed a bug on Launchpad for this after some testing: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1607779

---

If all of this doesn't work for you and you can't get Ubuntu installed without formatting the partition, then make a list of installed packages (dpkg -l with minimal scripting and review of the output can do this for you) and compare modifications you made to /etc and other directories. This is another reason to make backups: compare what previously had after a fresh install.

Comment: To switch back to the GUI it's Ctrl+Alt+F7.